# Using powershell to remove group from an NTFS folder fails with SeSecurityPrivilege after removing inheritence

Tags: powershell, ntfs, scorch

I've found an un-usual situation with Powershell 3.0 when trying to remove Domain Users from a users home drive, and want to reach out to see if anyone has any ideas as to why.

**Psudo code so you can understand what I'm trying to do**

```
 Create a new folder
 Grant User access to write their home drive
 Remove Inherited Permissions from folder
 Remove general access from all Domain Users
```

**Actual code (with error handling remove for simplicity)**

```
$UserName = "auser"
$Path = "\\domain.com\user\users\" + $UserName
$UserIdentityReference = "DOMAIN\" + $UserName

$NewFolder = New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Path

#Need to allow the user to write to the folder
$GrantUserAccesRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($UserIdentityReference, @("ListDirectory", "ReadData", "WriteData", "CreateFiles", "CreateDirectories", "AppendData", "ReadExtendedAttributes", "WriteExtendedAttributes", "Traverse", "ExecuteFile", "ReadAttributes", "WriteAttributes", "Write", "ReadPermissions", "Read", "ReadAndExecute", "Modify", "Synchronize"), "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl = Get-Acl $NewFolder
$acl.AddAccessRule($GrantUserAccesRule)
Set-Acl -aclobject $acl -Path $NewFolder

# Remove inheritence from parent folder.
$acl = Get-Acl $NewFolder
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)
Set-Acl -aclobject $acl -Path $NewFolder

#Need to prevent any domain user from accessing the folder
$acl = Get-Acl $NewFolder
$RemoveDomainUsersACLRule = $acl | Select -ExpandProperty Access | where-object {$_.IdentityReference -eq $UserIdentityReference}
$acl.RemoveAccessRule($RemoveDomainUsersACLRule)
#ERROR OCCURS HERE
Set-Acl -aclobject $acl -Path $NewFolder
```

**Error is:**

```
Set-Acl : The process does not possess the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege which is required for this operation.
At line:4 char:3
+   Set-Acl -aclobject $acl -Path $NewFolder
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\gifs.com\user\users\tautomation:String) [Set-Acl], PrivilegeNotHeldException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

What is strange is that as soon as I execute SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true), I can't add roles, or remove the role I just added.

**Things I've tried**

- I can remove the role that I added, as long as I do it before SetAccessRuleProtection.
- *Manually removing "Domain Users" group from File Explorer works.*
- *Running powershell as an elevated user.* This makes no difference

**Research Already done:**
I've read 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2010/11/12/how-to-handle-ntfs-folder-permissions-security-descriptors-and-acls-in-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like [this Connect bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/789418/unable-to-set-acl-using-set-acl-when-not-admin-on-acl-protected-folder). Instead of using Set-Acl, I always recommend using SetAccessControl() for files/folders (Set-Acl has some issues with the filesystem). I would change all Set-Acl calls to this:

```
(Get-Item $NewFolder).SetAccessControl($acl)
```